# FInding sum of values in a column for each identical other columns in a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am working on a `C# list` of type that I defined myself which has about 6 columns and several rows of data and I am trying to retrieve data of three columns which has same data in it and sum of other column associated with similar data.

For Example my `C# list` has following data

```
Time    Code Range  Unit   Type   Price Volume 
8:13:43 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.1   250
8:13:53 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.1   50
8:14:01 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.099 100
8:14:08 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.099 50
8:16:49 LN  V14     380/400 Call  0.063 50
8:17:04 LN  V14     380/400 Call  0.001 50
8:18:43 LN  N15-U15 450     Call  0.125 50
8:34:00 LN  F15      500    Call  0.053 200
```

From the above Data I want to retrieve one row for each similar Code,Range, Unit and Type and Sum of Volumes for all similar columns and store it another C# list So, I want the new list of four columns to be as follows

```
Code Range  Unit   Type  Volume
LN  N15-U15 300     Put   450 
LN  V14     380/400 Call  100
```

The above two rows are the only rows with similar `Code,Range, Unit and Type and Volume` is the Sum of all volumes of similar other columns

I am able to retrieve similar rows successfully but was not able to get the sum of volumes 
I have the following linq code

```
var result = from row in listStructures
                         group row by new { row.Code, row.range, row.Unit, row.Type} into grp
                         let Item = grp.First()                        
                         select new { Code= Item.Code, Range= Item.Range, Unit= Item.unit, Type= Item.type};

            listMicroSummary = new List<StructuresDS>();
            listMicroSummary.Add(new StructuresDS
            {
                Code= result.Select(x=>x.Code).ToString(),
                Range=result.Select(x=>x.Range).ToString(),
                Unit= result.Select(x => x.Unit).ToString(),
                Type= result.Select(x => x.Type).ToString(),
            });
```

**Is there a better way I can solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
var query = listStructures.GroupBy(row => new {row.Code, row.range, row.Unit, row.Type} )
                     .Select(grp => new StructuresDS
                     {
                         Code = grp.Key.Code,
                         Range = grp.Key.Range,
                         Unit = grp.Key.Unit,
                         Type = grp.Key.Type,
                         Volumne = grp.Sum(r=> r.Volume)
                     });
listMicroSummary = query.ToList();// if you want a List
```

- You do not need `grp.First()`, since you have all the fields as part
  of Key.
- Use [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.95).aspx) to sum the volume for each group.